# Why this buffer size is not properly handled by sockets?

Tags: c++, sockets

When I set BUF_SIZE to 10000 works fine but 50000 doesn't.
I'm just trying to send data from a client to a server and testing the buffer size, but I found that with certain sizes, the application doesn't work properly.

Why?? And how could I solve it??

For example, I run the server and the client, the first attempt work fine, but when I re-run the client, start the problems with the deliveries.

Here is the server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 50000

using namespace std;

void manejador(int signo);

int main()
{
    int     sservice, sclient,l,nbytes_read, err, nbytes_sent;
    bool    end;
    char    buf[BUF_SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in sin, clientfsin;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    sservice=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0); /*Open the socket*/
    if(sservice == -1)
    {
        perror("Server. Socket: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    sin.sin_family      = AF_INET;  /*ARPANET address family*/
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;   /*Accept connections on any Interface*/ 
    sin.sin_port        = htons(4000);          /*Service TSAP > 1023. CHANGE IT!*/

    /*Register the server in the system*/
    err=bind(sservice, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    if(err == -1)
    {
        perror("Server. bind: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /*Up to 5 waiting connections*/
    err = listen(sservice,5);
    if(err == -1)
    {
        perror("Server. Listen: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* Receiving requests loop */
    for(;;)
    {
        /*Accept a connection from a client*/
        l = sizeof(clientfsin);
        sclient = accept(sservice,(struct sockaddr *)&clientfsin, (socklen_t*) &l);
        if(sclient == -1)
        {
            perror("Server. Accept: ");
            continue;
        }

        signal(SIGCHLD,manejador);          //Quitar si ponemos waitpid
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == -1){
            printf("Error al crear el proceso hijo\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        if(pid){
            close(sclient);
            //waitpid(pid,&status,0); //Descomentar si usamos waitpid
        }else{

        close(sservice);    
        /*Give the service*/
        end = false;
        int i=1;
        while(!end && (i<=10)) 
        {   
            nbytes_read=recv(sclient,(char *)buf,sizeof(buf),0);


            if (nbytes_read > 0)
            {
                buf[nbytes_read]='\0'; 
                //cout << "SERVER>Server received: " << buf << endl;
                printf("Recepcion <%i>: Se han recibido <%i> bytes del cliente\n",i,nbytes_read);
                cout.flush();

                err = 0;
                //sprintf(buf,"%s_server",buf);
                nbytes_sent = send(sclient,(char *)buf,sizeof(buf),0);
                printf("Envio <%i>: Se han enviado <%i> bytes al cliente\n",i,nbytes_sent);
                i++;
            }
            else    
            {
                perror("Sever. Receive/read: ");
                end=true;
                err = -1;
            }
        }

        if(err >= 0)
            cout << "SERVER>Cliente Atendido" << endl;
        else
            cout << "SERVER>Finalizacion incorrecta del cliente" << endl;

        /*Never forget to close a socket!*/
        close(sclient);
        exit(0);
        }
    }

    close(sservice);
    printf("Fin server");

} /*main()*/

void manejador(int signo) //comentar si usamos waitpid
{
      int estado;
      wait(&estado);
}
```

And here is the client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 50000

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int     sock, err;
    bool    end;
    char    buf[BUF_SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in sout;

    sock=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0); /*Open the socket*/
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        perror("Client. Socket: ");
        exit(-1);
    }


    sout.sin_family      = AF_INET;                       /*ARPANET address family*/
    sout.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");     /*Which server?*/
    sout.sin_port        = htons(4000);                       /*Output port*/

    /*Connect to the server*/
    err = connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&sout, sizeof(sout));
    if(err == -1)
    {
        perror("Client. Connect: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    end = false;
    double t1,t2;
    while(!end) 
    {   
        /*Ask for the service*/
        //cout << endl << "CLIENT> Send a message...: " ;    cout.flush();
        //cin.getline(buf, 128);
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            timeval tim;
                    gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
                    t1=tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);

            err = send(sock,(char *)buf,sizeof(buf),0);

            if(err == -1)
            {
            perror("Client. Send/write: ");
            exit(-1);
            }
            printf("Envio <%i>: Se han enviado <%i> bytes\n",i+1,err);

            gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
                    t2=tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);
                    printf("%.6lf para el envio de <%i>\n", t2-t1,i+1);

            err = recv(sock,(char *)buf,sizeof(buf),0);
            printf("Recepcion <%i>: Se han recibido <%i> bytes\n",i+1,err);
            //cout << "CLIENT> Server response: " << buf;   
            cout.flush();
        }
        end=true;
    }

    close(sock);

} /*main()*/
```

Offtopic: Sorry for the comments in Spanish ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right but a TCP connection usually sends packets with sizes on the order of 1500 bytes (because of Ethernet connection limitations/standards). Why do you need to send packets that are 50000 bytes? Why don't you break up the packets in smaller chunks?

Comment: What do you mean by "the application doesn't work properly."? Please explain the error further.

Comment: In that line `nbytes_sent = send(sclient,(char *)buf,sizeof(buf),0);` you're trying to send the *whole* buffer back to the client. I think it should be `nbytes_sent = send(sclient,(char *)buf,nbytes_read,0);` instead.

Comment: What is the error? If it's a segfault, I think I know what's happening. Your trying to set the element right after the end of the `buf` array if you send a certain amount of data. How much data are you sending?

Comment: Could you narrow down the code? It's hard to give help with large code samples to go through.

Comment: You don't send packets with TCP, you send a stream of bytes. How that stream of bytes is packetized is up to your OS tcp/ip stack.

Comment: You are missing `MSG_WAITALL` in your call to recv. I updated my answer.

Comment: Could you please make it clear what symptoms you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Bugs:

1) Your server makes no attempt to ensure it has received a complete message.

2) Your server sends 50,000 bytes regardless of how many bytes it actually needs to send.

3) If your server actually reads 50,000 bytes, its attempt to add a terminating zero will overflow the buffer.

3) Your client sends 50,000 indeterminate bytes.

4) Your client ignores the number of bytes it has received.

5) The client does not ensure it actually received the terminating zero byte sent by the server.

But your biggest error is this: You have no sensible protocol. If the message is terminated with a zero byte, why send 50,000 bytes? And if your message is always 50,000 bytes, why doesn't the receiver try to receive 50,000 bytes?

I'll give you my standard advise I give every TCP programmer: Start out by developing a protocol and document it. The protocol should specify who sends and when. The protocol should specify how messages are framed. The protocol should specify rules for valid and invalid messages. The protocol should specify how dead connections are detected and handled. And so on.

It takes an hour or so to document a protocol properly, but it's well worth it. Without one, it's hard to tell which of my bugs above really are bugs. (For example, maybe you really are supposed to always send 50,000 bytes even if the message is just "hi". Is the server supposed to find the end of a message by the byte count or by the terminating zero? And so on.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran your programs. The problem is in your expectation of how `recv` works. You are expecting the receiver to always be able to read all `BUF_SIZE` bytes in a single read. If this is your expectation, then you should set the `MSG_WAITALL` flag in the last parameter in your `recv` calls. Although in blocking I/O the `send` call will remain blocked until all your bytes are sent, this is not true by default for `recv`. It will receive however much data is in the socket input queue, so the `recv` may be shorter than what you are expecting without the `MSG_WAITALL` flag.

As to why a smaller value of `BUF_SIZE` works and a larger one doesn't, this would be explained by the size of the socket input queue. You could try to use `setsockopt` with the `SO_RCVBUF` option to set it to something that matches or exceeds your `BUF_SIZE` and see if it makes it work for you. But, in real life, network conditions would dictate whether or not the input buffer stays full, so short reads are just something your program should deal with.

The rest of the answer addresses some style issues and a kind of "off by one" error in your code.

I noticed you are creating a rather large array off the stack. You might consider dynamically allocating it. One way of doing that would be to use a vector.

```
std::vector<char> buf;

buf.resize(BUF_SIZE);
nbytes_read = recv(sclient, &buf[0], buf.size(), 0);
```

The other thing of note (noticed by @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh) is that if `nbytes_read` has the value `BUF_SIZE`, then trying to `NUL` terminate the input is the wrong thing to do. It would access data outside of the buffer's region. If you really must `NUL` terminate, then with the vector, you can use `push_back`.

```
if (nbytes_read == buf.size()) buf.push_back('\0');
else buf[nbytes_read] = '\0';
```

But you should find it easier to just set the size of the buffer.

```
buf.resize(nbytes_read);
```

Then, when you echo the data back, you will only echo back what was read.

```
send(sclient, &buf[0], buf.size(), 0);
```